# I currently have a student visa in Norway, but want to intern in China for 4 months. I am a U.S citizen

Tags: visas, us-citizens, china, study, norway

Is it possible to have a student visa in Norway and apply for a working visa in China for four months?

Comment: Not enough for an answer but I don't see why not (you have to check regs of specific country). I've held more than one visa at once (UK student + australian work, French scientist + australian work) and usually countries only care that you will leave when you're finished, that you are legally who/where you say you are.